# Change background of list item

Tags: reactjs, list, react-native, listitem, react-native-flatlist

How can I change the background color of multiple list items when they are selected? I am using `react-native-accordian` and `react-native-collapsible` and using flat list within content.

```
_renderContent(section, i, isActive)
{
 //console.log("MY DATA---",section.time_slots);
  return (
    <List
      style={inStyles.body}
      containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={section.time_slots}
          renderItem={
            ({ item,index }) =>
            (
             <ListItem
             onPress={() => this.selectSlot(item,section.date,index)}

             style = {[inStyles.list , {marginLeft : 15}, {marginRight : 5},
               {backgroundColor: (this.state.selectedItem[index]) ? 'green' : 'red'}]}
               title={`${item}`}
               containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
             />
          )
        }
          keyExtractor={item => section.date+item}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          />
      </List>
    );
}
```

I just want to change the style of a list item dynamically using `TouchableOpacity`. But unable to do so.

Answer (score 4):

You should change your code as below, your class would be like this:

```
  contructor (props) {
    super(props)
    let selectedItemTemp = []
    for(let i=0; i<section.time_slots.length; i++) { //section.time_slots is your FlatList data
      selectedItemTemp.push(false)
    }
    this.state = {selectedItem: selectedItemTemp}
  }


  selectSlot = (item, section.date, index) => {
    let {selectedItem} = this.state
    selectedItem[index] = !selectedItem[index]
    this.setState({selectedItem})
    ... // your other codes
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
        <FlatList
          data={section.time_slots}
          renderItem={
            ({ item, index }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => this.selectSlot(item,section.date, index)}>
               <ListItem style = {[inStyles.list , {marginLeft : 15}, {marginRight : 5}, {backgroundColor: (this.state.selectedItem[index]) ? 'green' : 'white'}]}
                 title={`${item}`}
                 containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
               />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          } {item => section.date+item}
          ItemSeparatorComponeultiple Selectiont={this.renderSeparator}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
        />
      ...
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your code was a great help. But I am not exactly calling it within render. As I have edited above. There are  multiple  items associated with the same index as it is expandable list. So if I select an item at particular index , in every list that particular item is selected. The change is also reflected only after i re-expand the list.

Comment: Do you want me to modify my answer or your problem is solved?

Comment: My problem is just half solved. I think i need to use the header with index to provide a unique id to every list item. Can you tell me how?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what are you meaning. can you explain it more?

Comment: if I select item of a list every other list items are selected. I have attached screen-shots above